# Magento 2 event to extend payment methods functionality

Tags: php, magento, payment-method

I need help. I am creating a custom payment method for Magento 2. In the plugin, user needs to enter the keys. While saving the config, I want to check if the keys entered by the user are correct or not. If the keys are incorrect, I want to show a message informing user about the issue.

I have googled about it and I thought I have found the event `admin_system_config_changed_section_{sectionname}`. I implemented it, cleared the cache and recompiled the code but when I save the config data for the payment method plugin, it does not trigger the class. I looked into Magento documentation. I could not find the exact full event name for it. These are the full event name I tried:

`admin_system_config_changed_section_payment_methods`
`admin_system_config_changed_section_paymentmethods`
`admin_system_config_changed_section_sales`

**MyPayment/Payment/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="admin_system_config_changed_section_payment_methods">
        <observer name="my_payment_admin_system_config_changed_section_paymentmethods" instance="MyPayment\Payment\Observer\CustomPaymentMethodConfigObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**MyPayment/Payment/Observer/CustomPaymentMethodConfigObserver**

```
<?php

namespace MyPayment\Payment\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class CustomPaymentMethodConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // some codes that did not trigger
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `<backend_model>`

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if ($this->getValue() == '') {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException(__($label . ' is required.'));
    } else ($this->getValue())) {
         //custom validation here
    }

    $this->setValue($this->getValue());
    parent::beforeSave();
}
```

See

- https://github.com/magepal/magento2-preview-checkout-success-page/blob/master/etc/adminhtml/system.xml#L64
- https://github.com/magepal/magento2-preview-checkout-success-page/blob/master/Model/Config/Backend/ValidFor.php